# GCP Velostrata [migrate for COMPUTE engine] creation of cloud extension failed

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to test migration of a VM from AWS to GCP. The VPC and VPN between both clouds is set up correctly. When i try to create cloud extensions from Velostrata manager, it fails/impaired with the log "

Edge A  Instance Provisioning Status    Failed  Instance null is not accessible on port 443
Edge B  Instance Provisioning Status    Failed  Instance null is not accessible on port 443

Answer (score 0):

If you are using free google Cloud subscription then please increase your compute engine Persistent SSD quota by raising the request. The default quota is 100 GB but to deploy the cloud extension we need 500 GB for one node. Due to that deployment has getting failed.

Please request for 2 TB persistent SSD on any specific region and move forward with Migration.
Good Luck
Thanks